# Angular 5 - How to search/filter using HttpParams

Tags: node.js, angular

How do i properly use HTTPParams to apply filters and is this the right usecase for it.

A user can filter by multiple languages, types and interests.

**component.ts**

```
this.filterForm = this.fb.group({
        language: [],
        type: [],
        interests: [],
    })


    this.filterForm.valueChanges.subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        let filters = res;
        this.momentService.search(filters).subscribe((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        });
    });
```

This is what the data looks like

[image]

**.service.ts**

I pass the filters object to my service which makes an api call to /search

```
search(filters) {

    let endpoint = this.path + 'search';

    let params = new HttpParams().set('filters', filters);

    return this.apiService.get(endpoint, params);

}
```

> Request
>   URL:http://localhost:3000/api/moment/search?filters=%7B%22language%22:%5B%22Arabic%22%5D,%22type%22:%22classmates%22,%22interests%22:%5B%22Computer%20programming%22,%22Cryptography%22%5D%7D

**Backend /search**

```
search(req, res) {

    let search = req.query;
    console.log(search);
    return res.json(search);

    // TODO: Do search with filter objec.

 }
```

My node backend receives it like so, and i cannot do anything with this. I have tried using JSON.Stringfy to pass it to my back end but then i cannot convert the result back to object form once it becomes string.

```
{ filters: '[object Object]' }
```

I think i am not using HTTPParms properly.

Comment: How does your `apiService.get` method look like?

Comment: @cyrix pleas check this pastebin - https://pastebin.com/mDGA1vpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `fromObject` option of the `HttpParamsOptions`, for you case that would be:

```
search(filters) {
    let endpoint = this.path + 'search';
    let params = new HttpParams({ fromObject: filters });
    return this.apiService.get(endpoint, params);
}
```

Comment: This works nicely. So what does this fromObject do? There seems to be nothing in the documentation about HTTPParamsOptions

Comment: It creates an `HttpParams` map from an object, the implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.0.3/packages/common/http/src/params.ts#L99).

Comment: OK great thnks.